# General Reference for surface singularities

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, reference-request, singularity-theory

Is there any "standard" reference for (rational) singularities on algebraic surfaces? I'm aware of Artin's papers and the one of Brieskorn (*Rationale Singularitäten komplexer Flächen*), but they seem pretty dense to me. I'm looking for a more extensive treatment using consistent notation, ideally (chapters of) a book.

Comment: have you looked at chapter 4, Singularities and Surfaces, in Miles Reid's contribution, "Chapters on Algebraic Siurfaces", to the IAS/Park City mathematics series vol. 3,  Complex Algebraic Geometry, edited by Kolla'r?  He discusses rational and elliptic Gorenstein singularities, based on the standard papers.

Comment: @roy smith thanks for the reference, do you know more texts like this one?

Comment: There is some good stuff in Chapters 3 and 4 (I think) of Badescu's book. There is also Lipman's [classic paper](https://eudml.org/doc/103893).

Comment: @Hoot Badescu's detailed proof of the classification of rational double points is nice. Do you know anything similar for rational triple points? Artin doesn't really prove his classification (as far as I can see), he just gives the list.

Comment: From a analytic point of view, you may want to check out the book "Normal Two-Dimensional Singularities" by Henry B. Laufer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could have a look at the nice textbook by S. Ishii *[Introduction to Singularities](http://www.springer.com/us/book/9784431550808)*. Chapter 7 is devoted to normal two-dimensional singularities, with an extensive treatment of rational ones.

You might be also interested in T. Okuma's book *[Plurigenera of Surface Singularities](https://books.google.it/books/about/Plurigenera_of_Surface_Singularities.html?id=MK4rAAAAYAAJ&redir_esc=y)*. Many topics on rational singularities are discussed in Chapter 2.